# jedi with ein does not work

Tags: ein, jedi, jupyter

While Jedi works in python mode, it does not in ein (jupyter-notebook). If I run jedi:setup manually, both of jedi and auto-complete get listed among minor modes.

I use emacs 25.1.1 on Debian.
I use melpa.
Jedi 20160426.456 is installed.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- calling emacs: emacs
- run jupyter notebook: M-x ein:run
- open test notebook: click on test.ipynb
- setup jedi: M-x jedi:setup
- type any simple object, dot, tab, jedi does not function (e.g. if I try to type something for completion, e.g. a string with a dot, like "testobject". then string functions of testobject will not be listed for selection.)

Comment: Could you describe "does not work" a little more clearly?

Comment: 1. Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, preferably starting from `emacs -Q`. 2. Don't add info needed for the question to a comment. Put it in the question. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: No insight, but I'd be interested to know how to get this working too.